# Boolean to change value after certain steps followed

Tags: python, function, if-statement, boolean

Now, I just can't seem to figure it out

What i'm after I think is a global Boolean that'll be set to False unless door two has been accessed then it'll flip the Boolean to be True but because i'm invoking roomChoice() to go back to the start after entering room two it's all being restarted.
Just wondering the logic to achieve this.

try and ignore the horrible mess that is this code ha, I'm doing this program in an attempt to convert from Java to Python and learn Vim in the process, so just slowly learning here.

```
global key = False
def roomChoice():
    print("It is now time to make a decision, so go on, 1, 2 or 3")
    userinput = int(input())

    while userinput != 1 or 2 or 3:
        if(userinput == 1):
            print("Doors locked")
            roomChoice()

        elif(userinput == 1 and key == True):
            print(
                "You've entered the room, it's now time to decide if you want to steal the wallet?")
            userinput = input()
            if(userinput == "yes"):
                print("Nice move, quick lets get out of here")
                elevator()
            elif(userinput == "no"):
                print("Well, on your way back to the elevator someone sees you coming out of the apartment, later they realise a wallet has been stolen, because you have been seen at the crime you are falsely imprisoned for burglary. 10 years, the judge really didn’t like you.")
                exit()
            else:
                roomChoice()

        elif(userinput == 2):
            print("Oh look a key, I wonder if that'll get you into room one?")
            key = True
            roomChoice()

        else:
            roomChoice()
            break
```

Comment: What is `key` in here?

Comment: Key is the Boolean variable that I'd have set to False until the user enters door two.....

Comment: But you didn't declare anywhere

Comment: Not in this code I had it outside the def as a global but it didnt seem to work, I'll add it to the code to show my initial idea. I'll do a quick edit. Thanks for your help, legend!

Comment: Please abstain from messages as "try and ignore the horrible mess that is this code ha" - if your code is a "horrible mess", then please clean it before asking a question to the community.

Comment: The horrible mess is more in refrence to my skills in Python, I'd love to fix it but I don't have that ability as of yet. But point taken an noted.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: You just have a logic error in your first if/elif statement, you have to check that the key is still false in the if statement, or it will always execute instead of the elif below it.

*Did you try declaring the key as a global variable inside the function?*

```
key = False 

def roomChoice():
    global key

    userinput = int(input("It is now time to make a decision, so go on, 1, 2 or 3: ")) # you can pass the prompt string as a parameter to the input method

    while userinput != 1 or userinput != 2 or userinput != 3: 
        if(userinput == 1 and key is False): # key has not yet been found
            print("Doors locked")
            roomChoice()

        elif(userinput == 1 and key is True): # now key has been found
            print()
            userinput = input("You've entered the room, it's now time to decide if you want to steal the wallet? ")
            if(userinput == "yes"):
                print("Nice move, quick lets get out of here")
                elevator()
            elif(userinput == "no"):
                print("Well, on your way back to the elevator someone sees you coming out of the apartment, later they realise a wallet has been stolen, because you have been seen at the crime you are falsely imprisoned for burglary. 10 years, the judge really didn’t like you.")
                exit()
            else:
                roomChoice()

        elif(userinput == 2):
            print("Oh look a key, I wonder if that'll get you into room one?")
            key = True
            roomChoice()

        else:
            roomChoice()
            break
```

Comment: Yeah, doesn't seem to work, I assume its because after entering door two and collecting the key I need to go back to the room choice, so I'm doing this by calling the roomChoice() but doing so restarts the function, which then im assuming is restarting the key to empty or False.

Comment: Actually I just realized your problem, after adding a print statement at the beginning of the function to check the value of `key`, the variable does change as it is supposed to, but there is a logic error in your code. You must check the value of key in the first if statement to make sure it is false, otherwise it will always trigger instead of the elif block. See my updated answer.

Comment: Oh, I see you found that out too. :)

Comment: Ha yeah we both figured that one out at the same time! thanks for your help tho, always a fun mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, one of those fun kinds of answers, I just had to flip my if & elif around as it was meeting the requirements of the if statement so it was never getting to the elif section. Nice.

```
global key = False
def roomChoice():
    print("It is now time to make a decision, so go on, 1, 2 or 3")
    userinput = int(input())

    while userinput != 1 or 2 or 3:

        if(userinput == 1 and key == True):
            print(
                "You've entered the room, it's now time to decide if you want to steal the wallet?")
            userinput = input()
            if(userinput == "yes"):
                print("Nice move, quick lets get out of here")
                elevator()
            elif(userinput == "no"):
                print("Well, on your way back to the elevator someone sees you coming out of the apartment, later they realise a wallet has been stolen, because you have been seen at the crime you are falsely imprisoned for burglary. 10 years, the judge really didn’t like you.")
                exit()
            else:
                roomChoice()
        
        elif(userinput == 1):
            print("Doors locked")
            roomChoice()
        
        elif(userinput == 2):
            print("Oh look a key, I wonder if that'll get you into room one?")
            key = True
            roomChoice()

        else:
            roomChoice()
            break
```